# dylib: image not found, but the path looks correct

Tags: macos, dylib, launchd

On one computer, an OS X launchd daemon is crashing when it fails to load the MailCore framework.  However, the framework is in the expected location, and the daemon is running properly on my computer as well as several others'.  Does anyone know what might be causing the "image not found" error?  Or how to troubleshoot this issue?

The MailCore lib is installed at:

`/Library/Application Support/ArgusLink/bin/MailCore.framework/Versions/A/MailCore`

The binary trying to load it is installed at (and run via launchd):

`/Library/Application Support/ArgusLink/bin/arguslinkd`

The install name for MailCore is:

`@loader_path/MailCore.framework/Versions/A/MailCore`

MailCore is built for i386 architecture.  The computer on which the daemon crashed is running 10.6.8, with which I have tested successfully.

Full crash report:

```
Process:         arguslinkd [349]
Path:            /Library/Application Support/ArgusLink/bin/arguslinkd
Identifier:      arguslinkd
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-11-22 08:58:30.117 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @loader_path/MailCore.framework/Versions/A/MailCore
  Referenced from: /Library/Application Support/ArgusLink/bin/arguslinkd
  Reason: image not found

Binary Images:
0x8fe00000 - 0x8fe4162b  dyld 132.1 (???) <A4F6ADCC-6448-37B4-ED6C-ABB2CD06F448>
   /usr/lib/dyld
```

Comment: If youre running 10.6.8 shouldnt it be built for x86_64? (that doesnt seem to be the issue at the moment :-))

Comment: The application relies on libraries that couldn't easily be built for x86_64 (e.g. older video stuff), so we're using i386 as the only architecture.  But no, I don't think that's the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the advice at [Dave Dribin's Blog](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/11/15/rpath/), I switched to using `@rpath` instead of `@loader_path`, though I'm a little fuzzy as to why that might have fixed the problem.

Note that I had to use `@rpath/` instead of `@rpath` for the `Runpath Search Paths` value (the library is in the same directory as the loader executable), or I would otherwise continue to get "library not found" errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should add framework to "Embeded binaries" not to "Linked frameworks and libraries" (although it will add itself to Linked frameworks when you add it to Embeded binaries).